# How can I add a control template to a resource dictionary?

Tags: wpf, xaml

So I would like to create a template copy of a ComboBox, but not define it in the MainWindow, but in a specially created resource directory.

What i got:

```
<Application x:Class="dingeTesten.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:dingeTesten"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

And now i createt a RessourceDictionaray that got called Dictionary1.xaml. In this file i want the Template Copy of my ComboBox but when i create a template i cannot choose this file:
[image: Picture1]

Its in German but i cannot choose the last option RessourceDictionary to save this template in my RessourceDictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you are trying to create a style for `ComboBox` in `Blend`. To enable `Resource dictionary` option you have to add `ResourceDictionary` into `MergedDictionaries` in `App.xaml`.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary2.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then `Resource dictionary` option will be enabled.

[image]